# Generating random numbers...Faster way?

Tags: matlab, random

Using *Run & Time* on my algorithm I found that is a bit slow on adding standard deviation to integers. First of all I created the large integer matrix:

```
NumeroCestelli = 5;

lover_bound = 0;
upper_bound = 250;
steps = 10 ;

Alpha = 0.123

livello = [lover_bound:steps:upper_bound];
L = length(livello);

[PianoSperimentale] = combinator(L,NumeroCestelli,'c','r');
for i=1:L
    PianoSperimentale(PianoSperimentale==i)=livello(i);
end
```

then I add standard deviation (sigma = alpha * mu) and error (of a weigher) like this:

```
%Standard Deviation
NumeroEsperimenti = size(PianoSperimentale,1);

PesoCestelli = randn(NumeroEsperimenti,NumeroCestelli)*Alfa;
PesoCestelli = PesoCestelli.*PianoSperimentale + PianoSperimentale;
random = randn(NumeroEsperimenti,NumeroCestelli);
PesoCestelli(PesoCestelli<0) = random(PesoCestelli<0).*(Alfa.*PianoSperimentale(PesoCestelli<0) + PianoSperimentale(PesoCestelli<0));

%Error
IncertezzaCella = 0.5*10^(-6);
Incertezza = randn(NumeroEsperimenti,NumeroCestelli)*IncertezzaCella;
PesoIncertezza = PesoCestelli.*Incertezza+PesoCestelli;
PesoIncertezza = (PesoIncertezza<0).*(-PesoIncertezza)+PesoIncertezza;
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Can you provide a concise description of what type of values you're trying to generate?

Comment: I'm trying to simulate a [MultiheadWeigher](http://www.ishidaeurope.com/images/articles/CCW_em.jpg). Those hoppers are filled with materials (like pasta). The rows of  `PianoSperimentale` are the possibile configuration than the hoppers can assume, columns are the hoppers number. I need to creare a matrix with integer number (setup) and then add StdDev & error to simulater the all thing :)

The problem is very complex, so I hope I was clear

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example? So only include the lines that you want to speed up and make sure we have all information to run them. In the current example `combinator` is not defined for instance, but probably that part is not even relevant.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Unfortunately I can't make a more minimal working example (the real algorithm is much more complex). Combinator is a funcion, you can find it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24325-combinator-combinations-and-permutations). I need to know if there is something to speed up the StdDev and error part, or maybe the `for i=1:L` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information for me to test it, but I bet that eliminating all the duplicate calculations that you do will lead to a speedup. I have tried to remove some of them:

```
PesoCestelli = randn(NumeroEsperimenti,NumeroCestelli)*Alfa;
PesoCestelli = (1+PesoCestelli).*PianoSperimentale;
random = randn(NumeroEsperimenti,NumeroCestelli);
idx = PesoCestelli<0;
PesoCestelli(idx) = random(idx).*(1+Alfa).*PianoSperimentale(idx);

%Error
IncertezzaCella = 0.5*10^(-6);
Incertezza = randn(NumeroEsperimenti,NumeroCestelli)*IncertezzaCella;
PesoIncertezza = abs((1+PesoCestelli).*Incertezza);
```

Note that I reduced the last two lines to a single line.

Comment: Thanks @DennisJaheruddin, I fixed the only error `PesoIncertezza = abs((1+Incertezza).*PesoCestelli);` and now i compute in 487.7314 instead of 531.9824s.

Comment: I think you can also reduce the number of random numbers you generate `random = randn(sum(idx(:)), 1);` and then just use `random` instead of `random(idx)`.

Answer (score 1):

You calculate `PesoCestelli<0` a number of times. You could just calculate it once and save teh value. You also create a full set of random numbers, but only use a subset of them where `PesoCestelli<0`. You might be able to speed things up by only creating the number of random numbers you need.

It is not clear what `Alfa` is, but if it is a scalar, instead of

```
Alfa.*PianoSperimentale(PesoCestelli<0) + PianoSperimentale(PesoCestelli<0)
```

it might be faster to do

```
(1+Alfa).*PianoSperimentale(PesoCestelli<0)
```

Comment: Yep, `alpha is a scalar. Adding your advice I was able to reduce the computational time from 531.9824 to 498.7509.

Comment: Note that this should also be faster when `Alfa` is a matrix.